# how to make entity class for database in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, netbeans, hibernate-mapping

"Entity class from Database" is supported in Netbeans but in eclipse Indigo i tried alot but didn't find any way except entity class for JPA , i want to create entity class for Dynamic web project (struts2) for hibernate

Netbeans can create like this but why eclipse can not create "entity class from database" in such a way

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package temp;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Shakeel
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Email.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Email e"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Email.findByEmailId", query = "SELECT e FROM Email e WHERE e.emailId = :emailId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Email.findByUserId", query = "SELECT e FROM Email e WHERE e.userId = :userId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Email.findByEmailAddress", query = "SELECT e FROM Email e WHERE e.emailAddress = :emailAddress")})
public class Email implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private Integer emailId;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;
    @Column(name = "email_address")
    private String emailAddress;

    public Email() {
    }

   //all gatter and setter

}
```

Comment: http://www.kianworknotes.com/2012/12/how-to-generate-entities-from-tables.html.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting